# RESTful CRUD for Angular and Express $resource

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest, express, mean-stack

I have my JSON querying and creating correctly. I'm a bit stuck on how to remove items from the server. They are being removed in angular but I can't seem to get the connection right for removing them on the server.

My server.js:

```
var hcController   = require('./server/controllers/services-controller.js')

//REST API
app.get('/api/hc', hcController.list);
app.post('/api/hc', hcController.create);
app.delete('/api/hc:_id', hcController.delete);
```

My server-side model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   module.exports = mongoose.model('HealingCenterData',{
      title: String,
      shortname: String,
      summary: String,
      description: String
    });
```

My server-side controller

```
var Hc = require('../models/healingcenter-model.js')

module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var hc = new Hc(req.body);
  hc.save(function (err, result){
    res.json(result);
  });
}

module.exports.list = function (req,res) {
  Hc.find({}, function (err, results){
    res.json(results);
  });
}

module.exports.delete = function (req, res) {
  ???????
  });
}
```

My angular service:

```
app.factory("HC", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return {
        API: $resource('/api/hc/:id')
    }
}]);
```

My angular controller:

```
app.controller('servicesController', ['$scope', 'HC','$resource', function ($scope, HC, $resource) { 

  HC.API.query(function(results) {
        $scope.services = results;
    });

  $scope.createService = function() {
      var service = new HC.API();
      service.title = $scope.serviceTitle;
      service.shortname = $scope.serviceShortname;
      service.summary = $scope.serviceSummary;
      service.description = $scope.serviceDescription;
      service.$save(function(result){
        $scope.services.push(result);
        $scope.serviceTitle = '';
        $scope.serviceShortname = '';
        $scope.serviceSummary = '';
        $scope.serviceDescription = '';
      });
    }


$scope.removeItem = function(index){
    $scope.services.splice(index, 1);
  }

}]);
```

My JSON structure

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53bea9366a03a66c2dad68bb"), "title" : "Auto Clinic", "shortname" : "auto_clinic", "summary" : "Volunteers evaluate car problems and make minor repairs. Labor is free, and the car owner pays for any needed parts. Oil changes are performed at a reduced cost. All services are performed on Saturdays.", "description" : "No additional information yet.", "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: Can you post your `models/healingcenter-model.js'`

Comment: I've added the model to the question.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side try (I'm assuming you are using moongose)  :

```
exports.delete = function(req,res){
    if(req.params.id !==null || req.params.id!==undefined){
        Hc.remove({_id:req.params.id},function(err){
                res.send(200);
       });
    }
 };
```

on the client side:

**angular controller:**

```
var endPoint = $resource('/api/hc/:id', {id:'@tId'});
$scope.removeItem = function(id){
var ep = new endPoint({tId:id});
     ep.$delete(function(res){
         //TODO: update local array in scope
     });
};
```

**EDIT:**
you can just use the resource directly in the controller or just the service as you have done in your case, that's totally fine.

Comment: For some reason I'm returning the error "DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/hc 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

Comment: Make sure your $resource url matches the endpoint defined on your route in express

Comment: They are matching now, the disconnect may be from my mongodb generated "_id" instead of "id".

Comment: I've added my JSON structure for reference. '@tId' is new to me, what is this representing?

Comment: @tId is just a parameter for your local resource

Comment: What's the issue you are having now?

Comment: The same issue as before.

Comment: Check in the request if the id is in the url, you can do it using the developer tools in chrone

Comment: It isn't in the URL. My response is 
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/hc
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: that's the reason why isn't matching your endpoint the url should have an id on it as querystring

Comment: try to manually add and id and see if you reach that endpoint type in your browser something like localhost:3000/api/hc?id=53bea9366a03a66c2dad68bb

Comment: That endpoint does access the object when added directly into the browser as a URL.

Comment: ok that means for some reason you are not passing correctly the id from the angular client, double check if you are passing the id correctly to your "removeItem" function defined in your controller, post the markup related to that